# How to insert image in a listView (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

Please how can i insert images in a listView using XAML.

I just want to make a simple example : like inserting two lines : Banana and strawberry with a picture of them .

I already saw similar questions and tried the code, but it generated errors.

Here is my code :

```
<ListView  >

  <ListView.Template>
      <DataTemplate>
              <ImageCell  ImageSource="banana.jpg "Text="banana"/>
          <ImageCell ImageSource="strawberry.jpg" Text="Strawberry"/>
  </DataTemplate>   

  </ListView.Template>
</ListView>
```

The errors I'm getting are :

[image]

Comment: I know you're new, so please keep question material in the questions - only answers should go in the answers.

Comment: You should binding from the Viewmodel or specific page to listview ItemsSource in Xaml

Comment: PLease how can i do that ?